# Setup environment variable for doctrine and elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, symfony, elasticsearch

How to setup environment variable for symfony.

Like if i run my project than it should detetched the envirment and do the action, as an example ---

```
http: //production.com -> prod * environment *
http: //localhost:9200 -> * dev * environment --- for elasticsearch
http: //localhost:8000 -> * dev * environment --- for doctrine/mysql
```

So if i run a mysql request on localhost it should make the request at

```
http: //localhost:8000
```

and if i make a request for elasticsearch it should make the request at

```
http: //localhost:9200
```

and if it runs in the production environment it should do the request at

```
http: //production.com:9200 --- elasticsearch
http: //production.com:8000 --- doctrine/mysql
```

I think it can be done at `parameters.yml` but i really did not get how it can be done.

Can someone help me to solve this problem.
Thanks a lot in advanced .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's the problem here so I'll give you a more general answer.

Symfony has a really great way to configure your project for different situations (or environments). You should have a look at the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html) which explains things in depth.

By default, Symfony comes with 3 configurations for different environments:

1. `app/config/config_dev.yml` for development
2. `app/config/config_prod.yml` for production
3. `app/config/config_test.yml` for (unit) testing

Each of these config files can override settings from the base configuration file which is `app/config/config.yml`. You would store your general/common settings there. Whenever you need to override something for a specific environment, you just go to the environment config and change it.

Lets say you have the following base configuration in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%prod_database_host%"
        port:     "%prod_database_port%"
        dbname:   "%prod_database_name%"
        user:     "%prod_database_user%"
        password: "%prod_database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

Now lets say, you have 3 different databases for each environment - `prod`, `dev` and `test`. The way to do this is to override the configuration in the environment configuration file (lets say `app/config/config_dev.yml`:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%dev_database_host%"
        port:     "%dev_database_port%"
        dbname:   "%dev_database_name%"
        user:     "%dev_database_user%"
        password: "%dev_database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
```

Add the necessary `%dev_*%` parameters to your `app/config/parameters.yml.dist` and `app/config/parameters.yml`. Now, whenever you open your application using the `dev` environment, it will connect to the specified database in your parameters (`%dev_database...%`).

This is pretty much it. You can do the same for any configuration you need to be changed in a specific environment. You should definitely have a look at the documentation. It's explained straight-forward with examples.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)