# Multiple configuration Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony2 as framework to develop my application, but i currently use svn, and i need to setup 2 configurations on my project, 
The first configuration will be work with my server Mamp.
The second one, will be for my development environment server.

How to do this ?

Thanks all

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479992/setup-environment-variable-for-doctrine-and-elasticsearch/32485995#32485995).

Comment: Thank you for replying i will have a look :)